# PHP - What is the point of passing by reference?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Ok, I know what passing by reference is... I don't need that explained.

Say you have a function that takes in an argument by reference:

```
function foo(&$a){
   $a = 1;
}
```

and you call it:

```
$a = 0;
foo($a); // Now $a is 1.
```

You can do the same exact thing passing by value:

```
function foo($a){
   $a = 1;
   return $a;
}
```

and you call it:

```
$a = 0;
$a = foo($a);  // Now $a is 1.
```

So, what is the point of passing by reference?

Comment: For one thing, if you pass by reference, you can return one thing and still alter another, like `preg_match` for example (http://se1.php.net/preg_match).

Comment: Your example works when you only have 1 value to pass (which works as functions can only return at-most 1 value); what if you want to return more than 1 value from a function as output without having to create a tuple?

Comment: Both very good points.

Comment: A third point is more subtle: often it is more elegant to use a reference, since the calls syntax is different. Instead of that asignment you just call a "routine" which "does something" with something. Take this example: `validateOrReplace($document)`

Comment: Oh, and one more point, this one can actually be pretty important: a reference does by definition not copy the value. That can be a very important detail when you think about an object with a huge memory footprint, especially when such an object is handed through to multiple functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question from comments posted above and some other research:

1. Since only a reference to an object is passed to a function in pass-by-reference, it can be particularly useful when trying to conserve memory.
2. If there is such a case where you would want to alter an entity but return a different one, pass-by-reference can come in handy (although I would rather use multiple functions with return values).

Other than the two cases, I think this approach can cause confusion in large code bases and result in some nasty code.

If you know of any other reasons that I should add please comment and I'll add them here.